# Outputting a ruby Matrix in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If the following Matrix is being generated

```
@matrix = Matrix[[243, 256.0, 17762.980000000025], [363, 394.05, 27477.839999999997], [127, 495.5, 9712.96], [38, 249.0, 3497.8000000000006], [26, 110.0, 1365.4600000000005], [258, 650.0, 17966.500000000007]]
```

When they are rendered to view

```
<% @matrix.each do |item| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= item[0] %></td>
    <td><%= item[1] %></td>
    <td><%= item[2] %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

type errors are appearing, such as

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for 256.0:Float:
NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for 243:Fixnum
```

What is the proper way to invoke these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_vectors` to returns an array of row vectors:

```
<% @matrix.row_vectors.each do |row| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= row[0] %></td>
    <td><%= row[1] %></td>
    <td><%= row[2] %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This response is particularly valuable, as the Ruby docs page (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-row_vectors) is too curt (not very instructive) on this point. And it is a concise solution, to boot!